# How do I stop nested React components that dispatch Redux actions which update state from getting stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am having an issue with my nested react components getting stuck in an infinite loop.

The outer component is a `DashboardLayout`.  To separate redux logic from 'pure' layout logic I have divided the compnent as follows

```
DashboardLayout/
  index.js
  DashboardLayout.js
```

The dashboard layout is mapped to the route `/user`

The `index.js` is (roughly) as follows

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { submissions } = useSubmissionsPreloader()

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/dashboard') dispatch(replace('/dashboard/tasks'))
  }, [dispatch, pathname])

  return pathname === '/user' ? null : (
    <DashboardLayout submissions={submissions} selected={pathname} />
  )
}
```

`DashboardLayout.js` is roughly as follows

```js
const DashboardLayout = ({
  submissions,
  selected
}) => (
  <Container>
    <SegmentedController
      tabs={[
        { path: '/dashboard/submissions', title: 'My Submissions' },
        { path: '/dashboard/tasks', title: 'My Tasks' }
      ]}
      selected={selected}
    />
    <Switch>
      {dashboardRoutes.map(({ path, loader, exact }) => (
        <Route key={path} path={path} component={loadable({ loader })} exact={Boolean(exact)} />
      ))}
    </Switch>
    <h4>Submissions ({submissions.length})</h4>
    <Table
      headers={submissionsHeaders}
      rows={submissions.map(submissionsToRows)}
    />
  </Container>
)
```

This all works fine if the sub-component being mounted doesn't affect the redux state.  However if we take one of the sub-components as an example

```
Tasks/
  index.js
  Tasks.js
```

`index.js` is as follows

```js
const Tasks = () => {
  const { tasks } = useTasks()

  return <PureTasks tasks={tasks} />
}
```

and `Tasks.js` is simply this (doesn't actually care about the tasks yet)

```js
const Tasks = () => (
  <>
    <p>Tasks assigned to me go here</p>
  </>
)
```

The problem is that the `useTasks` is using a `useEffect` hook to dispatch a `loadTasks` action, a saga picks it up, makes an API call, and then dispatches `loadTasksSuccess` with the loaded tasks.  The reducer for that updates the tasks state with the tasks pulled from the api

`useTasks`

```js
export const useTasks = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector(getTasks)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const doTasksLoad = useCallback(() => dispatch(tasksLoad()), [dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    doTasksLoad()
  }, [doTasksLoad])

  return { tasks }
```

and the relevant bit of the saga

```js
function* worker({ type }) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'TASKS_LOAD':
      try {
        const tasks = yield call(loadTasks) // api call returns tasks
        yield put(tasksLoadSuccess(tasks))
      } catch (err) {
        yield put(tasksLoadFail(err))
      }
      /* istanbul ignore next */ break
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

Nothing controversial there.

The issue is that the change to the state causes the layout to re-render which causes the nested component to re-render which triggers the `tasksLoad` action again which triggers the `tasksLoadSuccess` action, which changes the state (`tasksLoad` sets `isLoading` to `true` and `tasksLoadSuccess` sets it to false again) and this causes an infinite loop.

I've got a gut feeling I ought to be using something like `useMemo` or `useRef` to somehow stop the constant re-rendering, but so far I'm not quite getting that to work either.

This general mechanism is fairly core to the way I was planning on building the app so I'd like to get it right.  If the nested component only reads from the state and doesn't change it then no re-rendering happens so a brute force approach would be to get the dashboard to simply preload everything it thinks it might need.  But that seems ugly to me.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to a better way to approach this?

Comment: A quick question, that `useEffect` in `useTasks` wouldn't seem to fire unless `doTasksLoad` changed in some way. It only changes when `dispatch` changes. This suggests to me that what is really going on is that the `Tasks` component is fully unmounting and then mounting again, is that the case?

Comment: Thanks - your comment pointed me in the right direction.  I've thanked you in my answer below.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

I have very less experience with Redux but i think const doTaskLoad is being assigned a function. If that is so then...
I think the problem over here is that you are using a function as a element in the dependency array of useEffect , as per the rules of React Render , every time a render happens every function is a new reference , hence React considers it as a new element and keeps on re rendering the value.

May i suggest using a primtive value for the dependency array

```
export const useTasks = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector(getTasks)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const doTasksLoad = useCallback(() => dispatch(tasksLoad()), [dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    doTasksLoad()
  }, [doTasksLoad])

  return { tasks }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what was wrong, with thanks to @cory-harper whose comment above pointed me in the right direction.

The `Tasks` component was indeed being reloaded.  This is due to how my `dashboardRoutes` were being described.

I render the individual routes as

```js
{dashboardRoutes.map(({ path, loader, exact }) => (
  <Route key={path} path={path} component={loadable({ loader })} exact={Boolean(exact)} />
))}
```

which is all well and good, and standard practice, when rendering entire scenes.  The loadable component wrapper ensures that the component is lazily loaded, and the route itself was being defined via a utility function `makeRoute` which is as follows

```js
const makeRoute = ([path, scene, permissionRequired = null, exact = true]) => ({
  path,
  loader: () => import(`scenes/${scene}`),
  permissionRequired,
  exact
})
```

So the `loader` asynchronously imports the correct component which is fine for an entire scene, but for the nested component it made react think the component was new each time, thus the useEffect was being called each time, thus the infinite loop.

By removing the fancy-pants lazy/asynchronous loading (not needed as these sub-components are tiny) and replacing that loop with

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/dashboard/submissions" component={Submissions} exact />
  <Route path="/dashboard/tasks" component={Tasks} exact />
</Switch>
```

the components no longer look unique each load, and everything works as expected.